# How to customize bin graph in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to customize some of the graph I am creating with R. The code I'm using looks something like this one

```
c1<-runif(5000, min=0, max=100)
c2<-sample(1:12, 5000, replace=TRUE)

dd<-data.frame(c1,c2)
g<-ggplot(dd, aes(c2, c1)) + 
    geom_bin2d(binwidth=c(2,5)) + 
    scale_fill_gradientn(colors=c("yellow", "red", "black")) +
    xlim(-1,13) + ylim(-5,55)
g
```

[image: plotted graph from code example]

How can I make so that the graph is contained between 0 and 12 and 0 and 50 (I tried to set these value but it cut off a portion of the bin, but it's very ugly to see this huge grey border around the graph)? I need essentially to have a white background (and I know how to do it) with the axis in black and adjacent to the actual plot.
Is there also a way to "smooth" the color gradient between each bin? The only way I know how to do it is reducing the number of bins but I need exactly those numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 g + scale_x_continuous(expand=expansion()) + scale_y_continuous(expand=expansion())
```

[image]

Check the documentation for `scale_x_continuous`, section for `expand` and

> `expansion`:   expand: For position scales, a vector of range
> expansion constants
> used to add some padding around the data to ensure that they
> are placed some distance away from the axes. Use the
> convenience function ‘expansion()’ to generate the values for
> the ‘expand’ argument. The defaults are to expand the scale
> by 5% on each side for continuous variables, and by 0.6 units
> on each side for discrete variables.

Comment: I tried to use it... it works, until I set limits in the scale, at which point I'm back at the same problem: the data go up to 300 on my real dataset, but I only need to show the interval between 0 and 100 
EDIT: also if I want to show the interval 0,100 I need to set -5,105 (adding essentially one bin for some reason I don't know )